# Can you define `Comonads` based on `Monads`?

Tags: haskell, transform, monads, comonad

Okay, so let's say you have the type

```
newtype Dual f a = Dual {dual :: forall r. f(a -> r)->r}
```

As it turns out, when `f` is a Comonad, `Dual f` is a Monad (fun exercise). Does it work the other way around?

You can define `fmap ab (Dual da) = Dual $ \fb -> da $ fmap (. ab) fb` and `extract (Dual da) = da $ return id`, but I do not know how to define `duplicate` or `extend`.

Is this even possible? If not, what the proof there is not (is there a particular Monad `m` for which you can prove `Dual m` is not a comonad)?

Some observations:
`Dual IO a` is essentially `Void` (and `Const Void` is a valid `Comonad`).
`Dual m a` for `MonadPlus m` *is* `Void` (just use `dual mzero`).
`Dual Reader` is `Env`.
`Dual Writer` is `Traced`.
`Dual State` is `Store`, I think.

Comment: I'm thinking you might make something of the fact that `Dual f a` is isomorphic to `forall r . Compose f ((->) a) r -> Identity r`, which I believe is the type of natural transformations from `Compose f ((->) a)` to `Identity`. I don't know enough to make much of it myself.

Comment: The answer is [no](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/monads-from-comonads/) according to Kmett.

Comment: Note that the cited blog only says such a comonad won't be useful 'in practice', even if it existed. In fact it exists, and I think it may be useful, as it geometrically encodes the structure of a data type.

Comment: Also, do note that combining laziness and fixpoints breaks parametricity and hence most of the categorical arguments in an intuitionistic calculus.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in fact any functor gives rise to a unique comonad in this way, unless f==0.

Let F be an endofunctor on Hask. Let

```
W(a) = ∀r.F(a->r)->r
W(f) = F(f∗)∗
       where g∗(h) = h∘g
```

The puzzle becomes geometric/combinatoric in nature once you realize the following isomorphism:

Theorem 1.

Suppose neither of the types (∀r.r->F(r)) (∀r.F(r)->r) is empty. Then there is an isomorphism of types W(a) ≃ (∀r.F(r)->r, a).

Proof:

```
class Functor f => Fibration f where
        projection   :: ∀r. f(r)->r
        some_section :: ∀r. r->f(r) -- _any_ section will work

to :: forall f a. Fibration f
      => (∀r.f(a->r) -> r)
      -> (∀r.f(r)->r, a)
to(f) = ( f . fmap const
        , f(some_section(id)))

from :: forall f a. Fibration f
        => (∀r.f(r)->r, a)
        -> (∀r.f(a->r) -> r)
from (π,η) = ev(η) . π

ev :: a -> (a->b) -> b
ev x f = f x
```

Filling up the details of this (which I can post on request) will require
a bit of parametricity and Yoneda lemma. When F is not a Fibration (as I defined above), W is trivial as you observed.

Let us call a fibration a covering if the projection is unique (though I'm not sure if this usage is appropriate).

Admitting the theorem, you can see W(a) as the coproduct of a's indexed by _all possible fibrations ∀r.F(r)->r, i.e.

```
W(a) ≃ ∐a
       π::∀f.F(r)->r
```

In other words, the functor W (as a presheaf on Func(Hask)) takes a fibration and constructs a canonically trivialized covering space from it.

As an example, let F(a)=(Int,a,a,a). Then we have three evident natural fibrations F(a)->a. Writing the coproduct by +, the following diagram together with the above theorem should hopefully be enough to describe the comonads concretely:

```
           a
           ^
           | ε
           |
         a+a+a
        ^  |  ^
     Wε |  |δ | εW
        |  v  |
(a+a+a)+(a+a+a)+(a+a+a)
```

So the counit is unique. Using evident indices into the coproduct, Wε maps (i,j) to j, εW maps (i,j) to i. So δ must be the unique 'diagonal' map, namely δ(i) == (i,i)!

Theorem 2.

Let F be a Fibration and let ΩW be the set of all comonads with the underlying functor W. Then ΩW≃1.

(Sorry I have not formalized the proof.)

An analogous combinatorial argument for the set of monads ΜW would be interesting too, but in this case ΜW may not be a singleton. (Take some constant c and set η:1->c and μ(i,j)=i+j-c.)

Note that the monads/comonads so constructed are *not* the duals to the original comonads/monads in general. For instance let M be a monad
(F(a)=(Int,a), η(x) = (0,x), μ(n,(m,x)) = (n+m,x)), i.e. a `Writer`. The natural projection is unique hence by the theorem W(a)≃a, and there is no way to respect the original algebra.

Note also that a comonad is trivially a Fibration (in possibly many different ways) unless `Void`, which is why you got a Monad from a Comonad (but that's not necessarily unique!).

A few comments about your observations:

- `Dual IO a` is essentially Void

  As far as I know, in Haskell IO is defined something like:

  ```
    -- ghc/libraries/ghc-prim/GHC/Types.hs
   newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
  ```

  which means from the type theory alone the corresponding covering is_   the unique canonical covering  space indexed by all `State# RealWorld`s. Whether you can (or should) reject this is probably a philosophical, rather than a technical question.
- `MonadPlus m => Dual m a` is Void

  Right, but do note that if F(a)=0 then W(a)=1 and it's not a comonad (because otherwise the counit  would imply the type W(0)->0 ≃ 1->0). This is the only case where W can not even be a trivial comonad given an  arbitrary functor.
- `Dual Reader` is..
  Those statements will sometimes be correct, sometimes not. Depends on whether the (co)algebra  of interest agrees with the (bi)algebra of coverings.

So I'm surprised how interestingly geometric Haskell really is! I guess there may be very many geometric constructions similar to this. For example a natural generalization of this would be to consider the 'canonical trivialization' of F->G for some covariant functors F,G. Then the automorphism group for the base space would no longer be trivial, so a bit more theory would be required to properly understand this.

Finally, here's a  proof of concept code. Thanks for a great refreshing puzzle, and have a very merry Christmas ;-)

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Comonad

class Functor f => Fibration f where
        x0 :: f ()
        x0 = some_section ()

        some_section :: forall r. r -> f(r)
        some_section x = fmap (const x) x0

        projection :: forall r. f(r) -> r

newtype W f a = W { un_w :: forall r. f(a->r)->r }

instance Functor f =>  Functor (W f) where
        fmap f (W c) = W $ c . fmap (. f)

instance Fibration f => Comonad (W f) where
        extract = ε
        duplicate = δ

-- The counit is determined uniquely, independently of the choice of a particular section.
ε :: forall f a. Fibration f => W f a -> a
ε (W f) = f (some_section id)

-- The comultiplication is unique too.
δ :: forall f a. Fibration f => W f a -> W f (W f a)
δ f = W $ ev(f) . un_w f . fmap const

ev :: forall a b. a -> (a->b)->b
ev x f = f x

-- An Example
data Pair a = P {p1 ::a
                ,p2 :: a
                 }
               deriving (Eq,Show)

instance Functor Pair where
        fmap f (P x y) = P (f x)  (f y)

instance Fibration Pair where
        x0 = P () ()
        projection = p1

type PairCover a = W Pair a

-- How to construct a cover (you will need unsafePerformIO if you want W IO.)
cover :: a -> W Pair a
cover x = W $ ev(x) . p1
```