# Does a natural monoidal structure on copoints of a Functor induce a Comonad?

Tags: haskell, algebra, category-theory, comonad

The situation is as follows (I changed to more standard-ish Haskell notation):

```
class Functor f => MonoidallyCopointed f where
    copointAppend ::  (∀r.f(r)->r) -> (∀r.f(r)->r) -> (∀r.f(r)->r)
    copointEmpty  ::  ∀r.f(r)->r
```

such that for all instance F of `MonoidallyCopointed` and for all

```
x,y,z::∀r.F(r)->r
```

The following holds:

```
x `copointAppend` copointEmpty == copointEmpty `copointAppend` x == x
x `copointAppend` (y `copointAppend` z) == (x `copointAppend` y) `copointAppend` z
```

Then is it true that F has a natural `Comonad` instance defined from `copointAppend` and `copointEmpty`?

N.B. The converse holds (with `copointEmpty = extract` and `copointAppend f g = f . g . duplicate`.)

EDIT

As Bartosz pointed out in the comment, this is mostly the definition of comonads using the co-Kleisli adjunction. So the question is really about the constructivity of this notion. Accordingly,
the following question is probably more interesting in terms of real-world applications:

Does there exist a constructive isomorphism between the set of possible `Comonad` instances of f and the set of possible `MonoidallyCopointed` instances of f?

This can be useful in practice because a direct definition of `Comonad` instance can involve a bit of
technical, hard-to-read code that cannot be verified by the type checker. For example,

```
data W a = W (Maybe a) (Int -> a) (Either (String -> a) (a,a,a,a))
```

has a Comonad instance but the direct definition (with the proof that it's indeed a Comonad!) may not be so easy.
On the other hand, providing a `MonoidallyCopointed` instance may be a little easier (but I'm not perfectly
sure of this point).

Comment: `e` seems to be a natural fit for the unit.  Do you have an idea how you might define, uh, comultiplcation? `f(r) -> f(f(r))`

Comment: @luqui: I think so, e would serve as the counit. Actually I want to check if (forall r. f(r)->r, a) is a Monad, f must be a Comonad. This was motivated by revising an answer I wrote to another question about Comonads.

Comment: @luqui: I mean this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302616/can-you-define-comonads-based-on-monads).

Comment: How about naming this something other but [`<*>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: What would be a good fit? I often use \otimes, but unicode characters often get in the way of correct indentation in Emacs. Any suggestion?

Comment: This is not strictly necessary, but I might better add the condition that f is additionally pointed (i.e. `forall r.r->f(r)` is inhabited). Then the question becomes about constructing suitable `extend` out of such 'points' of the functor.

Comment: This is almost the definition of a comonad using co-Kleisli arrows, except that co-Kleisli arrows can go between different objects (f a -> b). For this to be a comonad you'd have to extend <*> to the full-blown co-Kleisli composition operator =>=. I don't see how this could be done, unless you're working in a discrete category

Comment: @mnish huh? I use unicode characters all the time when coding Haskell in Emacs, don't see how `⊗` would be a problem. Nevertheless something ASCII like, whatever, `>*<` might be preferrable for compatibility.

Comment: @Bartosz Thanks, true enough! It would be quite interesting if that kind of high level statement actually leads to a concrete combinatorial description. You don't need to consider general co-Kleisli arrows, endomorphic arrows are enough as long as the derivation is natural.

Comment: Does the lens package do this?

Comment: Skimmed the documentation and I couldn't find a reason why it can't do this. Probably this is it.